# How to make the background a slideshow in javascript

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I attempted to make the background be a slideshow with javascript, but it's not working properly. Except for the first time the image changes after I hit refresh, everything works perfect. However, the first time the image changes, it glitches out, and the first image that fades away reappears for a split second and then disappears again. How do I fix this? Here is the code:

```
//The javascript code for the slideshow

//Create the slide show for the background
var backgroundImgS = "images/background1.JPG", backgroundImg2S = "images/background2.JPG", backgroundImg3S = "images/background3.JPG";

var backgroundImg = document.getElementById("backgroundImg"), backgroundImg2 = document.getElementById("backgroundImg2");
/*If the background slide show isn't transitioning, transNum increments every cycle. When transNum gets to a certain number, trans becomes true as the slide show starts to transition.
transNum is in that case returned to 0, and opacity goes down 10 per cycle (opacity is the opacity of backgroundImg). When opacity is at 0, backgroundImg is assigned the src of
backgroundImg2, and backgroundImg's opacity is returned to 100. After that, backgroundImg2's src is changed the the next image. imgNum determines which image the main background
image should contain.*/
var transNum = 0, opacity = 100, trans = false, imgNum = 0;

window.setInterval(function(){
    if(!trans) transNum++;//if the slide show isn't transitioning, increment transNum
    if(transNum == 100){//if transNum has counted to 100, start the transition of the background image
        transNum = 0;
        trans = true;
    }

    if(trans) opacity -= 10;//make the first image less transparent
    if(opacity == 0){
        trans = false;
        imgNum++;
        if(imgNum > 2) imgNum = 0;

        if(imgNum == 0){
            backgroundImg.src = backgroundImgS;
            backgroundImg2.src = backgroundImg2S;
        } else if(imgNum == 1){
            backgroundImg.src = backgroundImg2S;
            backgroundImg2.src = backgroundImg3S;
        } else if(imgNum == 2){
            backgroundImg.src = backgroundImg3S;
            backgroundImg2.src = backgroundImgS;
        } else{
            document.write("There was an error while running this page");
        }

        opacity = 100;
    }

    backgroundImg.style.opacity = opacity / 100;
    backgroundImg.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + opacity + ")";
}, 40);
```

Comment: I see you're new. Please be sure to accept the answer if it worked for you. =)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this working example from codepen.

[Pure JavaScript BackGround Image Slider](https://codepen.io/jayeshvekariya/pen/jPjWEM)

```js
  var slideCount = document.querySelectorAll('.slider .slide-item').length;
  var slideWidth = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-outer')[0].offsetWidth;
  var slideHeight = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-outer")[0].offsetHeight;

  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
  document.querySelectorAll('.slider')[0].style.cssText = "width:" + sliderUlWidth + "px";

  for (var i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.slide-item')[i].style.cssText = "width:" + slideWidth + "px;height:" + slideHeight + "px";
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    moveRight();
  }, 3000);
  var counter = 1;

  function moveRight() {
    var slideNum = counter++
      if (slideNum < slideCount) {
        var transformSize = slideWidth * slideNum;
        document.querySelectorAll('.slider')[0].style.cssText = 
          "width:" + sliderUlWidth + "px; -webkit-transition:all 800ms ease; -webkit-transform:translate3d(-" + transformSize + "px, 0px, 0px);-moz-transition:all 800ms ease; -moz-transform:translate3d(-" + transformSize + "px, 0px, 0px);-o-transition:all 800ms ease; -o-transform:translate3d(-" + transformSize + "px, 0px, 0px);transition:all 800ms ease; transform:translate3d(-" + transformSize + "px, 0px, 0px)";

      } else {
        counter = 1;
        document.querySelectorAll('.slider')[0].style.cssText = "width:" + sliderUlWidth + "px;-webkit-transition:all 800ms ease; -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);-moz-transition:all 800ms ease; -moz-transform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);-o-transition:all 800ms ease; -o-transform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);transition:all 800ms ease; transform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)";
      }

  }
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.main{
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider-outer{
   height:100% !important;
   
  overflow:hidden;
}
.slider{
 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
}
.slide-image{
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   display:block;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
}
.slider .slide-item{
  float:left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="slider-outer">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide-item"><span class="slide-image" style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1920x1000/FE0000);"></span></div>
      <div class="slide-item"><span class="slide-image" style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1920x1000/FEE000);"></span></div>
      <div class="slide-item"><span class="slide-image" style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1920x1000/FE00C7);"></span></div>
    
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's a perfect slideshow, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm trying to have the first image slowly fade away and have the image behind it become the main image for the background. Then I'm trying to repeat the process and have the secondary image fade away again for the third image to become the main image in the background, and repeat the process for the third image to fade away and have the first image become the background again. This would then keep repeating itself. Any suggestions to fix my code?

Comment: Sounds like you want fadein and fadeout effects. I’m on my phone right now. In the mean time, research these keywords.